# Inhomogeneous partial differential equation with 3 variables.

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I have an PDE in the form of,

$$a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + b\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + c\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + u = x + y + z$$

where $u\equiv u(x,y,z)$

I have tried to solve this problem by saying

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{b}{a} = 1$$
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{c}{a} = 1$$

Thus,
$$y=x+k \rightarrow \eta \equiv y-x=k$$
$$z=x+k \rightarrow \gamma \equiv z-x=k$$

where $a=b=c=1$

From here I have set $$\xi=x$$,
$$\eta=y-x=y-\xi$$,
$$\gamma=z-x=z-\xi$$

Then I have set $u(x,y,z)=w(\xi,\eta,\gamma)$

and tried to find $$\frac{dw}{dx}=\frac{dw}{d\xi}\frac{d\xi}{dx}+\frac{dw}{d\eta}\frac{d\eta}{dx}+\frac{dw}{d\gamma}\frac{d\gamma}{dx}$$ and similar things for $\frac{dw}{dy}$, $\frac{dw}{dz}$.

At the end I end up with

$$\frac{dw}{d\xi}+w=3\xi+\eta+\gamma$$

so how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = x + y + z-u$$
Quick overview of the solving :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{dz}{1}=\frac{du}{x+y+z-u}$$
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}\quad\implies\quad x-y=c_1$$
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dz}{1}\quad\implies\quad x-z=c_2$$
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{x+y+z-u}=\frac{du}{x+(x-c_1)+(x-c_2)-u}\quad\implies\quad \frac{du}{dx}+u=(3x-c_1-c_2)$$
$$e^x(u-3x+3+c_1+c_2)=c_3$$
$$c_3=F(c_1,c_2)\quad\implies\quad e^x(u-3x+3+c_1+c_2)=F\bigg((x-y),(x-z)\bigg)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.
$$e^x(u-3x+3+(x-y)+(x-z))=F\bigg((x-y),(x-z)\bigg)$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y,z)=x+y+z-3+e^{-x}F\bigg((x-y),(x-z)\bigg)}$$
This is the general solution of the PDE. This includes an infinity many particular solutions since $F$ is an arbitrary function.

The function $F$ has to be determined if some valid boundary conditions are specified.

Note : The above general solution can be written in many equivalent ways. For example :
$\quad u(x,y,z)=x+y+z-3+e^{-y}\Phi\bigg((y-x),(y-z)\bigg)\quad$ with arbitrary function $\Phi$ . The functions $F$ and $\Phi$ are related . If different methods of solving the PDE (without boundary condition) lead to apparently different solutions (at first sight), in fact the solutions are the same but written on different equivalent forms.

Comment: thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

We get $\frac{dx}{dt}=a,\frac{dy}{dt}=b,\frac{dz}{dt}=c,$ and $\frac{du}{dt}=x+y+z-u$.

This implies $x=at+k_1,y=bt+k_2,z=ct+k_3$ where $k_1,k_2,k_3$ are arbitrary constants. This yields the first order linear ODE $$u'+u=(a+b+c)t+(k_1+k_2+k_3)$$ whose general solution is $$u=(a+b+c)(t-1)+(k_1+k_2+k_3)+k_4e^{-t}$$ We can write the previous equation as $$e^{x/a}\big(u-x-y-z+a+b+c\big)\equiv \text{constant}$$ But since $ay-bx\equiv \text{constant}$ and $az-cx \equiv \text{constant}$ the general solution to your PDE is $$f\Big(ay-bx,az-cx,e^{x/a}\big(u-x-y-z+a+b+c\big)\Big)=C$$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $C$ is some constant. For example, taking $f(x,y,z)=z-x^2-y^2$ and $C=2$ yields $$u(x,y,z)=e^{-{x \over a}}\Big[(ay-bx)^2+(az-cx)^2+2\Big]+x+y+z-a-b-c$$ which you can verify [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8a7sdsmf5g) is a solution to your PDE.

Comment: I have already set $a=b=c=1$ the terms in your expression making things a bit confusing..Are you sure that's the right answer...wolframalpha gives different results..

Comment: In my solution $f$ is *any* differential function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $C$ is any constant. I just took $f(x,y,z)=z-x^2-y^2$ and $C=2$ for illustrative purposes, but you can call $f$ and $C$ anything you want and you'll get another solution. What does Wolfram produce? Also, why even include the constants $a,b,c$ if you're going to set them to be $1$?